# Yii CJuiDialog isn't being recognized

Tags: yii, cjuidialog

I've went through this tutorial http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/561/ajax-login-form-with-validation-errors-inside-jquery-modal-dialog/ It appears to be functioning properly, but instead of the form being in the modal dialog, it just renders it right on the page like zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog isn't even there.

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
'id'=>'login-dialog',
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Login',
    'autoOpen'=>false,
),
));?>


<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'user_login_form',
 'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
  'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'clientOptions'=>array(
                 'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                 'validateOnChange'=>true,
                 'validateOnType'=>false,
  ),
)); ?>
<h1>
Login</h1>
<p>
Please fill out the following form with your login credentials:</p>
<p class="note">
Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<div id="login-error-div" class="errorMessage" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array("onfocus"=>"$('#login-error-      div').hide();")); ?>
  <?php //echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
 </div>
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array("onfocus"=>"$('#login-error- div').hide();")); ?>
  <?php //echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
  <p class="hint">
   Hint: You may login with <tt>demo/demo</tt>.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="row rememberMe">
  <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->label($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
  </div>
<div class="row submit">

  <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                            'Sign In',
    array('/site/login.GetLogin'),
                            array(  
            'beforeSend' => 'function(){ 
                                         $("#login").attr("disabled",true);
        }',
                                    'complete' => 'function(){ 
                                         $("#user_login_form").each(function(){ this.reset();});
                                         $("#login").attr("disabled",false);
                                    }',
               'success'=>'function(data){  
                                         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
                                        // View login errors!
     // alert(data);
                                         if(obj.login == "success"){
                                     $("#user_login_form").html("<h4>
Login Successful! Please Wait...</h4>
");
                                     parent.location.href = "/";
                                  }
      else{
                                            $("#login-error-div").show();
                                            $("#login-error-div").html("Login failed!    Try again.");$("#login-error-div").append("
");
                                         }

                                    }' 
),
                     array("id"=>"login","class" => "btn btn-primary")      
            ); ?>

 </div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
 <!-- form -->

<?php $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog'); ?>
```

Its suppose to render like this above so when i click the link below it opens

```
echo CHtml::link('Login', array('/site/login.GetLogin'), array('onclick'=>'$("#login-dialog").dialog("open"); return false;'));
```

Its built in a widget, if you have a look at the tutorial. Here's the complete widget

```
<?php

class loginProvider  extends CWidget{

public static function actions(){
    return array(
               'GetLogin'=>'application.components.actions.getLogin',
    );
}

public function run(){

    $this->renderContent();

}

protected function renderContent(){

 echo '<span style="float:right;">';
 if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
        echo CHtml::link('Login', array('/site/login.GetLogin'),    array('onclick'=>'$("#login-dialog").dialog("open"); return false;'));
 echo '</span>';
 $this->getController()- >renderPartial('application.components.views.login',array('model'=>new LoginForm)); 
 }
 else      
 echo CHtml::link('Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', array('site/logout'),     array('visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest));
 echo '</span>';
   }

}
```

Comment: where is the code for getLogIn action?

Comment: make this, 'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,